# How to include URI.js library in a Angular2+ app?

Tags: angular, webpack

I'm trying to find a way to include a third party library (**urijs**) in my angular2+ app. Below you'll find the files concerned.

```
// package.json
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "urijs": "^1.18.10",
    ...
  }
  ...
}

// .angular-cli.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": ["../node_modules/urijs/src/URI.js"],
  ...
}

// file.service.js
declare const URI: any;
...
...
URI.expand(..);
```

Doing simply that, I have an error when running my application.

```
ERROR TypeError: URI.expand is not a function
at ProfileService.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/shared/trakt/users/profile.service.ts.ProfileService.retrieveProfile (main.bundle.js:1071)
at HeaderComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/home/header/header.component.ts.HeaderComponent.ngOnInit (main.bundle.js:239)
at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (vendor.bundle.js:59912)
at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (vendor.bundle.js:61408)
at checkAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:61347)
at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (vendor.bundle.js:62208)
at debugCheckDirectivesFn (vendor.bundle.js:62149)
at Object.eval [as updateDirectives] (ng:///HomeModule/HomeComponent.ngfactory.js:13)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (vendor.bundle.js:62134)
at checkAndUpdateView (vendor.bundle.js:61314)
```

Any idea how I can include **urijs** library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If urijs doesn't include native Angular/Typesript support you'll need to also include a typings file so the compiler knows how to use the library:

https://github.com/typings/typings
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

Comment: I found that there is a [typings file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/urijs) for this library.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution. I don't know if it is correct but it works. I'm using `angular@4.0.0` and `angular-cli@1.2.0`.

You need to add `URITemplate.js` with `URI.js` in the `scripts` array in `.angular-cli.json` file.

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/urijs/src/URI.js",
    "../node_modules/urijs/src/URITemplate.js"
]
```

The issue [UriTemplate needs to be defined globally #297](https://github.com/medialize/URI.js/issues/297) in URI.js repository helped me.